# A limit with inifinite product

Tags: limits

How to find the limit $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\prod_{n=0}^\infty(
\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^n})^{x^n}$?

At first glance, I invoke Bernoulli inequality to estimate the power $x^n$ as $1+n(x-1)\leq x^n\leq 1$. Then we can find some cancellations. However, $1+n(x-1)$ seems to be rough...

Comment: Do you mean $x\to1^+?$  When $x<1$ the $n$th term goes to $0$.

Comment: @saulspatz the left limit as $x\to 1$. So $x<1$.

Comment: I was taught that, by definition, an infinite product does not converge unless the $n$th term goes to $1$.  If you define the product as the limit of the sequence of partial products, however, then it's $0$ when $x<1$ so the limit would be $0$.

Comment: Maple says $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( {\frac {1+{x}^{n+1}}{1+{x}^{n}}} \right) ^{{x}^{n}}=1$$ when $0<x<1$.

Comment: Take logarithms. My computations show that the limit is $e^{2a-1}$ where $a=1-\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 3 -\frac 1 4+...$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How to compute then? Could you give some hints?

Comment: Use the series expansion of $\ln (1+x)$ for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. However, I got stucked by encountering $\exp[-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{k+1}\frac{1}{1-x^{k+2}}]$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then take limit, however, Ifind the limit is $e^{\ln 2-1}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy. If $a=1-1/2+1/3_1/4+..$ .then $a=\ln 2$ and $e^{2a-1}=4/e$... Also $e^{\ln 2-1}=2/e.$